# Cómo defino un método fuera de mi Clase para que sus objetos puedan usarlo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, poo, funciones

Cómo defino un método fuera de mi Clase para que sus objetos puedan usarlo?
Si utilizo una función static puedo acceder a ella pero el objeto no puede!!

```
class  Tabla{
    static mensaje:string = 'hola 1';
    static muestraMensaje:() => void;
};
const tablero = new Tabla();
 
// Quiero definir el método fuera de la clase (no quiero que con el tiempo mi clase llegue a parecerse a una vaca preñada)
Tabla.muestraMensaje = function(){
    console.log(this.mensaje);
}
Tabla.muestraMensaje() // salida: 'hola 1' (hasta aqui es correcto)
 
// El problema lo tengo con los objetos. Por ejemplo:
tablero.mensaje = 'hola 2' // error porque 'mensaje' es static!

// Luego quiero ver el nuevo mensaje enviado a tablero
tablero.muestraMensaje(); // error pues el metodo es static!
```

Answer (score 1):

Para extender una clase existente podemos usar la sintaxis de prototipo.

```
Tabla.prototype.muestraMensaje2 = function() 
{
    // Más código
    // Puedes acceder a miembros del objeto con la palabra clave this
 }
```

Como lo tenías estabas definiendo una función estática standalone.

Aparte, los miembros que declaraste son estáticos por lo que pertenecen a la clase misma y no a una instancia de la clase. Esto significa que no los puedes acceder desde un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente esa era la solución. Gracias JhonRayo99.
Aquí el código corregido:

```
class  Tabla{
    visible:boolean;
    constructor(visible:boolean){
        this.visible = visible;
    }
    muestra() {}
};

Tabla.prototype.muestra = function(){
    Tabla.prototype.visible = false;
    console.log(this.visible);
}
const tablero = new Tabla(true);

Tabla.prototype.muestra();
tablero.muestra();
```

Comment: En lugar de publicar tu código corregido como respuesta, lo adecuado es marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te sirvió.